# A problem on Inner Product Space and Commutator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, inner-products

I want to get you guys help on this problem.

Consider $f$ is an element in Hilbert Space $H$, also $A$ and $B$ are both bounded, self-adjoint operators.$[A,B]=AB-BA$.

We want to show that $ \langle[A,B]f,f\rangle = 2\|Af\|\|Bf\|$ if only if  there exists a real number $c$ such that $Af=cBf$.

I always get the left hand side of the equation is 0 and $\|Af\|\|Bf\|=0$, which means $c=0$. So at least one of the norm is 0.

I don't think it is right. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: The left hand side isn't always zero, but if $A=cB$, then $[A,B] = cA^2-cA^2 =0$. Are you sure this problem was copied correctly?

Comment: @3-in-441: I think that the left-hand side is always zero, since $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint.

Comment: The left-hand side is not necessarily $0$: take $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$.